# Backup oracle 11g XE user

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, backup, rman

I'm using Oracle 11g XE and I want to make a backup for the database that I'm working on it using RMAN,

the command "Backup Database" backing up the whole database, with all its users.

Is there a way to backup only the user that I'm working on, without backing up the other users ?

Comment: If you want to backup a specific user and schema, use expdp.

Comment: no, that's an export, I need a backup functionality, using RMAN